# printing the switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

my question is pretty simple, what I want to do is print the switch case name that is set when the user enters the values . Lets assume that

```
   switch (name.toLowerCase()) {
            case "john":
                salary = 12;
                break loop;

            case "jack":
            case "jonathen":
                salary = 6;
                break loop;

            default:
                System.out.println("\n\tWrong Name Dude!");
                break;

        }
        System.out.print(name)
```

What i want to do is when the user enters john , or JOHN or JoHn i just want 'john' to be printed . Which is the case '  ' name . The issue is if i use the assigned string to print it , the to.lowercase will identify that it is "john" when "JoHn" is entered , but when printing it would print "JoHn" instead of "john" any suggestions ?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Use `toLowerCase()` when you print just the same as you did for the switch? Or instead of calling the method 2 times, just make name lowercase before doing all this. `name = name.toLowerCase()`

Comment: What loop are you breaking out of with break loop;?

Answer (score 3):

change your code like this:

```
name = name.toLowerCase();
switch (name) {
        case "john":
            salary = 12;

            break loop;
        case "jack":
        case "jonathen":
            salary = 6;
            break loop;
            default:
            System.out.println("\n\tWrong Name Dude!");
            break;

    }
    System.out.print(name)
```

the reason is that `name.toLowerCase()` just return the lower case of name variable but it won't change the name itself, so you have to assign the return value to the name.

Answer (score 1):

Try simply to print `name.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Cant believe i forgot this , ashamed i even asked . Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class in Java is immutable, meaning that once a String object is created whatever operation you perform on it won't change the object's value but, instead, it will return **a new** String which is the result of the method you invoked (`toLowerCase` in this case).

In order to achieve what you want you just need to store the reference of the brand-new string into another variable.
You could try something like this:

```
switch (name = name.toLowerCase()) {
        case "john":
            salary = 12;

            break loop;
        case "jack":
        case "jonathen":
            salary = 6;
            break loop;
            default:
            System.out.println("\n\tWrong Name Dude!");
            break;

    }
    System.out.print(name)
```